# Аудиозаписи в VK API

Tags: vkontakte-api

Как можно обойти запрет VK API на аудио? Пытался и через [http://api.я.ws](http://api.%D1%8F.ws), но все таки хотелось бы обойтись без него. Пробовал также и авторизацию через оф приложения, типа Windows Phone, Android, Kate Mobile, но выдает либо ошибку 9, либо ошибку 14. Что я делаю не так? Ведь например здесь: https://apidog.ru все работает через Кейт мобайл.

Comment: обходить запрет - нелегально) а в итоге могут так или иначе прикрыть всё, точно также, как с offline

Comment: А какие цели Вы преследуете? Есть вариант "костыльный", мне в некоторых задач помогает: разместить аудио где-либо(к примеру: на стене, для множественных вариантов можно попробовать wiki-страниц, но не испытывал это на практике), и с помощью метода запроса данных(wall.get) можно получить данные об аудио, включая ссылку.

Answer (score 2):

Обойти **легально** это ограничение нельзя, но есть способ **нелегальный**, за который можно получить **реальный срок**, так что решать Вам.

За предоставленную информацию и её использование не несу никакой ответственности, всю ответственность на себя берёт тот человек, который использует эту информацию.

Итак, для начала Вам нужно просканировать трафик оф.приложения/kate mobile с подменой сертификатов, в то время как вы будете заходить в аудиозаписи, а затем проанализировать трафик и понять, как работает kate/официальное приложение. Сейчас уже не работает способ, который я нашёл до этого(я его не использовал в своих и чужих целях), поэтому конкретно сказать не могу.

Просканировать трафик можно с помощью приложения packet capture, но оно, как я понял, не может поймать *все* пакеты.

Comment: Вариант вполне неплохой, только есть вероятность, что используется официально API, ибо VK могли выдать доступ, как вполне неплохой версии мобильного клиента.